# Priority queue with AWS SQS and Lambda as consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a messaging use case question.

As of now, we have a queue in AWS SQS, say, ***origQueue*** and out-of-the-box-lambda-based-message-consumption on that queue.

Now to cater to one particular feature of priority (High,Medium,Low) based message consumption (on the basis of a 'priority' number set within the message), I am thinking to have a set of 3 queues, wherein each queue is pertaining to a different priority level. On the highest priority queue, out-of-the-box-lambda-based-message-consumption would continue to happen. A batch process would keep running in an interval of 5 mins. each to promote some messages from the mid and low priority queues. The logic of this batch process has not been thought of currently, but it could be anything, say pick up 10 Medium priority messages and 5 low priority messages , both aged more than 1 hour and promote them to the high priority queue, so that they can be consumed by the above mentioned out-of-the-box-lambda-based-message-consumption.

So before going that way, I just wanted to gather other potential ideas. Is there any out-of-the-box AWS feature or any pattern to solve this priority based message consumption problem?

P.S.

Another (not chosen) approach I came up with was to 'insert' the items in the queue considering the priority which would keep the queue always ordered by priority. But this 'run-time-dynamic-insertion' does not seem feasible as the stream of incoming messages is always on.

Comment: interesting problem. Alternative solution might be to store all the messages in rdb table, run the cron task (e.g. in lambda) that queries the highest priority messages from db and processes them. The query itself would contain the rules that determine priority of messages. Out of curiosity, which problem are you trying to solve with this queues?

Comment: Also curious as to the use-case / problem you're solving here.

Comment: Thanks for the approach Molecular Man. This new table would have to go to an existing DB, and that means, polling from a lambda/batch might put a load there. SQS and out-of-the-box-lambda-based-message-consumption are more cloud native in my opinion. The design problem at hand is that I have a lambda content generator and a lambda content dispatcher, decoupled by a queue. A new use case which has come in demands content dispatcher to dispatch high priority items first if there are different priority items in there.

Answer (score 6):

There is now the concept of Message Groups for FIFO (First in, First Out) SQS queues.  This allows you to send a message to the SQS queue with a particular ID, in which the queue will automatically group it for you in the order it receives new items.

Interacting code can query the overall SQS queue with a Message Group parameter and will receive back any messages in that queue. Using something like ReceiveMessage [(Node.js link provided)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html), one can provide the parameter "MessageGroupId" which will then fetch one or more messages (in the order received) with a matching "MessageGroupId".

A basic high level concept would be to have the code always checking the high priority message group until it determines it is empty, and then moving to the medium (and then the low) priority queues to process work there until a new entry in a higher priority queue is found.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS recommended way is as you first suggest, to have 3 separate SQS queues, ie one for each priority level. See the [suggestion here](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/features/) at the bottom of the page. Whatever consumes each queue will have to be coordinated separately, as none of the queues 'knows' what their priority is inherently.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any solutions rather than using multiple queues. Also, a simple and elegant solution for ensuring scalability is to use Event Source Mappings, and, when a message arrives check if it came from the priority queue. If it did, process it. If it didn't, check if the priority queue has messages in it, and either put the message back on the queue, or continue processing it.